# NSTimer and CADisplayLink conflict

Tags: iphone, timer, game-loop

I have a CADisplayLink as my main gameloop for a game, and a NSTimer that spawns enemies every ten seconds. I use...

```
    -(void)togglePause{
displayLink.paused = !displayLink.paused;
if (displayLink.paused) {
    [self.view addSubview:pauseOverlay];
}else {
    [pauseOverlay removeFromSuperview];
}
```

...to pause the gameloop, but the timer that spawns enemies will continue to go on even after the games paused, if I destroy the timers and then make another one couldn't p just exploit the pause button and just hit it before the 10 seconds go off causing enemies never to spawn?
Is there an easy solution to this?

Comment: well you must check if displayLink.paused is true or not. provide more code please.

Comment: I showed the full method now, I don't see why that's important though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ditch the NSTimer and just use a counter that you increment each time the CADisplayLink fires. Once it reaches *n* spawn your enemies and zero the counter. If the user pauses, when they resume the counter will be the same as it was.